Parallelize web scraping with python and selenium
I am trying to scrape health data from the Brazil health data repository here. I am trying to get the number of visits to the doctor for Anxiety/Depression, for each month, for the years 2018 to 2024, for each sex(M/F), and for 22 different age groups. I have the list of A/D codes (54), and want to see how many visits each code had, separately. I have a dataframe in which each row is one combination of these variables (54codes X 2sexes X 22 age groups X 7 years):
combns = pd.read_csv("/.../data/Anxiety_Depression_combinations.csv")

code    year    sex codeType    agelower    ageupper
0   F32 2018    2   CID 0   200
1   F320    2018    2   CID 0   200
2   F321    2018    2   CID 0   200
3   F322    2018    2   CID 0   200
4   F323    2018    2   CID 0   200
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
16627   P01 2024    3   CIAP    100 200
16628   P02 2024    3   CIAP    100 200
16629   P74 2024    3   CIAP    100 200
16630   P79 2024    3   CIAP    100 200
16631   P82 2024    3   CIAP    100 200
16632 rows × 6 columns

For each line in the dataframe, I change the settings, then scrape the resulting html table and save it as an Excel file. I have this code to open a web browser in headless mode, and select some common settings:
url = "https://sisab.saude.gov.br/paginas/acessoRestrito/relatorio/federal/saude/RelSauProducao.xhtml"
DRIVER_PATH = '/home/kvemuri/.local/share/binman_chromedriver/linux64/128.0.6613.119/chromedriver'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless=new")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH,options=options)
#driver.quit()

    # Open browser and navigate to SISAB website.
    #DRIVER_PATH = '/home/kvemuri/.local/share/binman_chromedriver/linux64/127.0.6533.119/chromedriver'
    #driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
    #url = "https://sisab.saude.gov.br/paginas/acessoRestrito/relatorio/federal/saude/RelSauProducao.xhtml"
    driver.get(url)
    # Set type of service - Individual
    driver.find_element(By.ID,"tpProducao").send_keys('Atendimento Individual')
    
    # Set column to month (Competencia)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="selectLinha"]/optgroup[1]/option[6]').click()
    
    # Set Type of team
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="filtroEquipeProf"]/div[1]').click()
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="filtroEquipeProf"]/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a/label/input').click()
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="filtroEquipeProf"]/div[1]/ul/li[5]/a/label/input').click()
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="filtroEquipeProf"]/div[1]/ul/li[9]/a/label/input').click()
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="filtroEquipeProf"]/div[1]').click()
    
    # Set place of service
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="filtrosLocalTipoEstabelecimento"]/div/button').click()
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="filtrosLocalTipoEstabelecimento"]/div/ul/li[2]/a/label/input').click()
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="filtrosLocalTipoEstabelecimento"]/div/button').click()
    
    # Set type of service - Individual
    driver.find_element(By.ID,"tpProducao").send_keys('Atendimento Individual')
    
    # Set type of attendance - select all
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="divTipoAtendimento"]/div/button/span').click()
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="divTipoAtendimento"]/div/ul/li[1]/a/label').click()
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="divTipoAtendimento"]/div/button/span').click()
    
    # Set type of professional
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="filtroEquipeProf"]/div[2]/button/span').click()
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="filtroEquipeProf"]/div[2]/ul/li[12]/a/label').click()
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="filtroEquipeProf"]/div[2]/ul/li[19]/a/label').click()
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="filtroEquipeProf"]/div[2]/button/span').click()
    
    # Select 'years' button for age
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="tpIdade:2"]').click()

I have the following functions:
def createXpathPattern(code,codeType):
    if codeType == 'CID':
        codeXpath = '//*[@id="cid-{}-1"]'.format(code)
        #code = code
    else:
        codeXpath = '//*[@id="cid-{}-4"]'.format(code)


def setDxCode(code, codeType):
    if codeType == 'CID':
        codeXpath = '//*[@id="cid-{}-1"]'.format(code)
        #code = code
    else:
        codeXpath = '//*[@id="cid-{}-4"]'.format(code)
    #codeXpath = '//*[@id="cid-{}"]'.format(code)
    #codeXpath = createXpathPattern(code = code, codeType = codeType)
    driver.find_element(By.ID,"btnAddCid").click()
    time.sleep(1)
    searchBox = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="dtBasicExample_filter"]/label/input')
    searchBox.clear()
    searchBox.send_keys(code)
    #time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,codeXpath).click()
    searchBox.clear()
    #time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="modal-default-cid"]/div/div/div[2]/button[2]/span').click()
    
# function to set age group and sex

def setAgeLimit(agelower, ageupper):
    
    """Selects the upper and lower age limit in years, and the sex for which data is to be output"""
    
    #Set lower age limit
    agelim1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="idadeInicio"]')
    agelim1.clear()
    agelim1.send_keys(str(agelower))
    
    #Set uper age limit
    agelim2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="idadeFim"]')
    agelim2.clear()
    agelim2.send_keys(str(ageupper))
    

def setSex(sex = 1):
    # Set Sex
    sexXpath = '//*[@id="filtrosCaracteristicaUsuario"]/div/ul/li[{}]/a/label'.format(sex)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="filtrosCaracteristicaUsuario"]/div/button/span').click() #//*[@id="filtrosCaracteristicaUsuario"]/div/button
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,sexXpath).click() # //*[@id="filtrosCaracteristicaUsuario"]/div/ul/li[2]/a/label/input
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="filtrosCaracteristicaUsuario"]/div/button/span').click()
    
# Get list of all months in the months column in the webpage
monthBoxes = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#competencia > div > ul > li > a> label > input")
yearMonth = []
for i in range(len(monthBoxes)):
    yearMonth.append(monthBoxes[i].get_attribute("value"))


def getMonthsforYear(year):
    year = str(year)
    boolMonth = [year in i for i in yearMonth]
    return(list(compress(yearMonth,boolMonth)))


def ClickMonthCheckbox(monthsList):
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="competencia"]/div/button/span').click()
    for month in monthsList:
        monthIdx = str(yearMonth.index(month) + 1)
        monthxpath = '//*[@id="competencia"]/div/ul/li[{}]/a/label/input'.format(monthIdx)
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH,monthxpath).click()


def SelectAllMonthsInaYear(year):
    TmpMonthsList = getMonthsforYear(year)
    ClickMonthCheckbox(TmpMonthsList)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="competencia"]/div/button/span').click()
    

def checkboxIsSelected(monthsList):
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="competencia"]/div/button/span').click()
    for month in monthsList:
        monthIdx = str(yearMonth.index(month) + 1)
        monthxpath = '//*[@id="competencia"]/div/ul/li[{}]/a/label/input'.format(monthIdx)
        checkbox = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,monthxpath)
        print(checkbox.is_selected())


def checkboxYearIsSelected(year):
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="competencia"]/div/button/span').click()
    TmpMonthsList = getMonthsforYear(year)
    checkboxIsSelected(TmpMonthsList)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="competencia"]/div/button/span').click()
    

def getHTMLtable():
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="j_idt44"]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/label').click() # Click on submit button
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="tabela_length"]/label/select').send_keys('100') # Set number of rows in table to 100
    t = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="tabela"]').get_attribute('outerHTML') # //*[@id="tabela"]/tbody
    table = pd.read_html(t,thousands ='.')
    table_dt = pd.concat(table)
    #table_dt['sex'] = 'Female'
    #table_dt['agelower'] = 5
    #table_dt['ageupper'] = 9
    return(table_dt)


def SetParametersAndGetTable(agemin,agemax,sex,year, code, codeType):
    if sex == 1:
        sexL = "Both sexes"
    elif sex == 2:
        sexL = "Males"
    else:
        sexL = "Females"
    
    dlCode = code + "." + str(year) + "." + sexL + "." + str(agemin) + "." + str(agemax)
    
    setAgeLimit(agelower = agemin,ageupper = agemax)
    SelectAllMonthsInaYear(year)
    setSex(sex = sex)
    setDxCode(code = code, codeType = codeType)
    time.sleep(1)
    try:
        table_dt = getHTMLtable()
        table_dt['code'] = code
        table_dt['sex'] = sexL
        table_dt['agelower'] = agemin
        table_dt['ageupper'] = agemax
        table_dt = table_dt[['code','sex', 'agelower', 'ageupper','Competência','Atendimento Individual']]
        table_dt.rename(columns = {'Competência':"YearMonth",'Atendimento Individual':"individual.visits", 
                               'code':'code','sex':"sex",'agelower':"agelower",'ageupper':"ageupper"},inplace= True)
        table_dt['YearMonth'] = pd.to_datetime(table_dt['YearMonth'], format = "%Y%m").dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
        setDxCode(code = code, codeType = codeType) # Unselect code
        time.sleep(1)
        setSex(sex = sex) # Unselect Sex 
        SelectAllMonthsInaYear(year) # Unselect yearMonth parameters
        return(table_dt)
    except:
        print(f'Table not found for {dlCode}')
        setDxCode(code = code, codeType = codeType) # Unselect code
        time.sleep(1)
        setSex(sex = sex) # Unselect Sex 
        SelectAllMonthsInaYear(year) # Unselect yearMonth parameters


def ApplyRows(row):
    year = row['year']
    sex = row['sex']
    agelower = row['agelower']
    ageupper = row['ageupper']
    code = row['code']
    codeType = row['codeType']
    
    if sex == 1:
        sexL = "Both sexes"
    elif sex == 2:
        sexL = "Males"
    else:
        sexL = "Females"
    
    anx_dep_key = code + "." + str(year) + "." + str(sex) + "." + str(agelower) + "." + str(ageupper)
    print(anx_dep_key)
    table_name = "~/sisab/data/anxiety_depression_with_codes/sisab_anx_dep_code_{}_{}_{}_{}_to_{}.xlsx".format(code,str(year),sexL,str(agelower),str(ageupper))
    print(table_name)
    
    try:
        print("Scraping code {}, year {}, for {} in age range {} to {}".format(code,str(year),sexL,str(agelower),str(ageupper)))
    
        table_dt = SetParametersAndGetTable(agemin = agelower,agemax = ageupper,sex = sex,year = year, code = code, codeType = codeType)
        table_dt.to_excel(table_name,index = False,header = True)
        Anx_Dep_dict[anx_dep_key] = table_dt
    except:
        notRun = {'Code':code,'codeType':codeType,'Year':year,'Sex':sex,'agelower':agelower,'ageupper':ageupper}
        noRun.append(notRun)

And then apply the ApplyRows() function over each row of the dataframe of combinations.
noRun = []
Anx_Dep_dict = {}
combns.apply(ApplyRows, axis = 1)

My problem is, each row takes about 20 seconds to run, and with ~ 17000 rows, that means more than 3 days for all the rows to complete running, if there is no issue.
I am trying to see if there is a way to parallelize it with Dask. I am not sure if I need to use Dask.dataframe, or dask.delayed, or both, and how I would use them. I am looking for any pointers on how to do this, and would appreciate any help.
Thanks a lot!!

Can you not just use concurrent.futures and multiple Selenium webdriver instances?

That's a lot of code to go through. You could do some profiling - maybe even something as simple as start = time.time() globally at the start of your code, then print("some identifying text", time.time() - start) sprinkled in critical parts of your code. Then focus on that one part by removing everything else in a test script to post here. For example, you seem to have removed code in your main loop which may be the most important part. Eg., do you get a new driver for each row? If the slowness is in fetching pages, that's all this question should be about.

@tdelaney, apologies for the wall of code. The only bit of information I omitted was the actual dataset of combinations that I am working with. The rest of the functions go into the main function, which is ApplyRows(), and running that for one row takes about 20 s, which I have profiled. I am also not opening a new driver for each row, and that is part of my confusion: should I be opening a new driver, or would that only  delay the whole process?

there's nothing in that code that stands out as being inefficient.  I'm guessing that most of that 20seconds is the server being slow as most guv'ment servers are.  To speed up other things, you might consider using HTMLUnit as the driver/browser.  (It's basically a light-weight browser)  You might also consider only saving results to file(s) when the script is complete.

I rolled back your latest edit. Feel free to post it as an answer if that was your intent, or post a new question (probably with a link back to here) if you now have a new question.
